# White space between <h3> <h4> and <p> tags

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My code is simple here, although I still can't figure out how to remove the white gap that is in between each tag. You can see it between the h3 and h4 tags with the background colors. How do I get rid of this space?

```css
.realEstatePricing h3 {
  Background: lightblue;
  height: 40px;
}

.realEstatePricing h4 {
  Background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<section class="realEstatePricing">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h3 class="text-center">Photo Package</h3>
        <h4 class="text-center">$99</h4>
        <p>description 1</p>
        <p>description 1</p>
        <p>description 1</p>
        <p>description 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Set: `margin: 0` on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a response to the other answers you can do this:

```
.realEstatePricing h3 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.realEstatePricing h4 {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

This way your overall left and top margins will remain in their current state.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding margin to 0 for both of them

```css
 .realEstatePricing h3 {
   Background: lightblue;
   height: 40px;
   margin:0;
  }
 .realEstatePricing h4 {
   Background: lightgrey;
   margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="realEstatePricing">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Photo Package</h3>
                    <h4 class="text-center">$99</h4>
                    <p>description 1</p>
                    <p>description 1</p>
                    <p>description 1</p>
                    <p>description 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </section>
</body>
</html>
```